# AWS ALB: How do I redirect to another domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-elb

I have a server behind an ALB that works great.

All traffic that comes to http://api.example.com is forwarded by the ALB to an EC2.  My ALB is listening on HTTPS:443 and forwards the request to an EC2 - HTTP: 3000

**Question:**
While keeping the setup describe above, how do I configure my ALB to forward/redirect all traffic that comes to
**http**://www.example.com and **https**://www.example.com and send it to https://apps.example2.com/somepath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your question so that you want to keep the current configuration and copy traffic to a new location.

ALBs do not support traffic mirroring but you could mirror traffic from EC2 instances to a new location:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/traffic-mirroring-getting-started.html#step-create-traffic-mirroring-sessions